# Request.HTML - only returning <body> content not full <html> content

Tags: xmlhttprequest, mootools

When I perform a `Request.HTML` through mootools, the `responseHTML` property only contains the contents of the  tag and not the full  content that can be found in the response body.

Can anyone explain why - and if it is possible to retrieve the full HTML?
I've got an existing application which requests an "email preview" via ajax and then drops the response into an iframe but recently the iframe has lost the CSS and it is due to the Request.HTML's responseHTML property not containing the full html.

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BloodBaz/n7nwhkc9/3/

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: NOTE: If I use mootools 1.2.6 I get the full HTML back.  Latest mootools, only the <body> content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Request.HTML` was conceived as a way to retrieve fragments, like templates/partials and convert into a node tree.

It makes sense to skip `<head />` in that context, as injecting styles, scripts etc may be completely undesired - you can see it here https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Request/Request.HTML.js#L38, where the context is being shifted into body, if there is one.

the script tags from the body are also extracted and put aside, run if `evalScripts` is set to true.

You don't need to use Request.HTML if you care about the full body and not the parser, just use `Request()` or reference `this.response.text` property in your success handler.

for instance: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/n7nwhkc9/5/

you should still not use `Request.HTML` if you don't rely on the xml parser to get you the node tree.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitar.  I discovered the #L38 that you referenced but your explanation in the first sentence really help to understand *why* it is doing this.  I do find MooTools documentation very limited - little more than a reference + examples.

And thanks for the work around and JSFiddle fix.  This has really helped.